# XtraReport print all from DataSet. I want print only selected in datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress, windows-forms-designer, xtrareport

I need code for selected in datagridview and after selected print in XtraReport.
This way I pick up the selected rows, what do I need next?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                bool isCellChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                if (isCellChecked == true)
                {

                    var allCheckedRows = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                               .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: Have you designed the report yet? What is the data source for your DataGridView? If it's bound to a List<T>, you can also bind a report to that same List<T>. If you use the DevExpress XtraGrid control, you can use it's built-in functionality for printing/exporting only selected rows.

Comment: Yes, I have report. Datagridview source is from dataset. I dont have a List<T>

Comment: Then you need to create a DataSet of the filtered rows and use this for the XtraReport's data source as well.

Comment: Okay, it sounds easy, but it's hard for me to do. I already have a dataset, maybe you mean in the code to make a new DataSet?

Comment: You have a collection of DataGridViewRows but you really need a DataTable/DataSet to which the XtraReport can be databound. Can you convert that collection to a DataTable/DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked fine for me in WinForms …

To select Visible in Gridview:

```
    private DataTable GetVisible()
    {
        //Export GRIDVIEW to DataTable
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        foreach (GridColumn column in gridView1.VisibleColumns)
        {
            DT.Columns.Add(column.FieldName, column.ColumnType);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = DT.NewRow();
            foreach (GridColumn column in gridView1.VisibleColumns)
            {
                row[column.FieldName] = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, column);
            }
            DT.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return DT;
    }
```

To show Preview form:

```
        private void FullBtnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Reports.FullList Rep = new Reports.FullList
        {
            DataSource = GetVisible()
        };
        using (ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(Rep))
        {                
            // Invoke the Print Preview form
            // with the specified look and feel setting.
            printTool.ShowPreviewDialog(UserLookAndFeel.Default);
        }
    }
```

To Print data:

```
        private void FullBtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Reports.FullList Rep = new Reports.FullList
        {
            DataSource = GetVisible()
        };
        using (ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(Rep))
        {
            // Invoke the Print Preview form
            // with the specified look and feel setting.
            printTool.Print();
        }
    }
```